# Trouble with multiplying bases

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I don't know if I'm having a problem doing the correct calculations but I can't seem to make the two methods agree. I'm trying to multiply 31 and 2 in base 5.

Method 1:
$$31_5\:\cdot \:2_5=112_5$$
$$1_5\:\cdot \:2_5=2_5$$
$$3_5\:\cdot \:2_5=11_5$$
$$110_5\:+\:2_5=112_5$$
Using a base calculator also returns $112_5$.

But in method 2:
Converting to decimal first,
$$31_{10}\:\cdot 2_{10}=62_{10}\:=\:222_5$$
What sort of leap in logic am I making here? They obviously aren't equivalent.

Comment: $31_5\ne31_{10}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting from base five to base ten by simply using the same digits and changing the base doesn't work. $31_5$ is $16_{10}$, not $31_{10}$. So the correct way of applying method 2 is
$$
31_5\cdot 2_5 = 16_{10}\cdot 2_{10} = 32_{10} = 112_5
$$

Comment: Ah, I see, every time I've done something like that the numbers were less than the base, which is why it worked before.

Comment: @GabN. Yes, it is true that for instance $4_5 = 4_{10}$, so the first time you encounter operands greater than or equal to $5$, that's a potential pitfall.

Comment: Not to mention, an odd number in an odd base, will have an odd number of odd digits. so 31 in base 5 clearly represents an even number.